# Round corner window Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to create a tkinter window with round corner similar to the window in the below image. Any suggestions will be really helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The window is controlled by your OS, not tkinter, so you can't do anything in python as far as I know. That's not to say you can't just make your OS have rounded corners, which assuming you have [Windows and are on update 1903](https://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-try-out-the-rounded-corners-ui-in-windows-10-version-1903-526546.shtml), shouldn't be too hard to do.

Steps from article:

Open the registry editor and locate `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\`

Right-click in the right page of the screen and create a new DWORD 32-bit Value called:
`ImmersiveSearch`

Then locate
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\Flighting\`

This time, you need to create a subkey of Flighting. So right-click the Flighting folder > New and name the new key:
`Override`

And finally, select the recently-created Override key and then right-click in the right pane to create a new DWORD (32-bit Value) called:
`ImmersiveSearchFull`

Double-click ImmersiveSearchFull to change its value and enter 1 using your keyboard.
In the same location, create a new DWORD (32-bit Value) called:
`CenterScreenRoundedCornerRadius`

Do the same thing to change its value, but this time enter 9.

Reboot your computer for the changes to go into effect.