# How to get rid of square edges in tkinter python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window, tk-toolkit

So I have been building this GUI using Tkinter and I actually don't like the edges of the window(squared) the next better ooption is tto have them rounded more like the Windows 11 when you open an app so I have tried to do it myself but that messed my whole code and after looking in it, it wasn't even rounding the window more like the frame I made so I have [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAvPP.png) which is how the window looks now and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUGPi.png) is how I want it to look

```
GUI:
from tkinter import *


root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background = "#110a60")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = 750, width = 800, bg = "#110a60")
canvas.pack()

root.resizable(False, False)
 
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "black")
frame.place(relheight = 0.8, relwidth = 0.8, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1)

start_button = Button(root, text = 'Start Program', padx = 10, pady = 5, fg = "#FFFF00", bg = "#012456", command = Script)
start_button.place(x = 350, y = 680)

exit_button = Button(root, text = 'Exit', padx = 20, pady = 5, fg = "#FFFF00", bg = "#012456", command = exit)
exit_button.place(x = 368, y = 714.5 )

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: tkinter has no control over this. You'll have to find an external platform-specific library.

Comment: @BryanOakley can you specify please I am new to python and still learning so I need all the help I can get

Comment: I can't help, I have no idea what to use, I've never needed to do this.

Comment: Oh okay I guess I will try and search in this time hoping that someone used something like this before comments

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/63262867